# How to paginate entities with OneToMany relationship with Fetch without warning firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch?

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I would like to be able to create pagination for pulling all customers from the database (MYSQL), but I encountered a hibernate n+1 problem, which I then solved, but I encountered another problem: 2023-02-09 16:57:04.933 WARN 11660 --- [io-8080-exec-10] o.h.h.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl : HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!

This problem I tried to solve with EntityGraph, but still nothing. Then I tried to use two Query, which collected the id and then used the IN clause, but this caused a huge sql query, which led to the generation of many "IN" which, with a huge dataset, can be problematic.

I am currently in a quandary and do not know how to solve this problem. I would like the figures to be fetched along with the customers, but I have no idea how to do it in such a way that the pagination works properly

I want to return CustomerDTO who have numberOfCreatedFigures attribute which is mapping from method in customer entity. This method is returning a size of customer figures.
I am using lombok for args/getters/setters. I've been trying to do everything, but nothing seems to fix the issue.

**Config class with a mapper**

```
@Bean
public ModelMapper modelMapper() {
    ModelMapper modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
    modelMapper.createTypeMap(Customer.class, CustomerDTO.class)
            .addMappings(mapper -> mapper
                    .map(Customer::numberOfCreatedFigures, CustomerDTO::setNumberOfFigures));
    return modelMapper;
}
```

**Customer class**

```
public class Customer implements UserDetails, Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   @NotBlank(message = "Your name cannot be blank")
   private String name;
   @NotBlank(message = "Your name cannot be blank")
   private String surname;
   @NotBlank(message = "Your login cannot be blank")
   private String login;
   @NotBlank(message = "Your password cannot be blank")
   private String password;
   @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
   private Role role;
   private Boolean locked = false;
   private Boolean enabled = true;
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "createdBy",
        cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST},
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        orphanRemoval = true)
   @ToString.Exclude
   private Set<Figure> figures = new HashSet<>() ...;
```

**Figure class**

```
public abstract class Figure implements Serializable {
   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
   private Long id;
   @Column(updatable = false, insertable = false)
   private String figureType;
   @Version
   private Integer version;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "created_by_id")
   @CreatedBy
   @ToString.Exclude
   private Customer createdBy;
   @CreatedDate
   private LocalDate createdAt;
   @LastModifiedDate
   private LocalDate lastModifiedAt;
   @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
   @JoinColumn(name = "last_modified_by_id")
   @LastModifiedBy
   @ToString.Exclude
   private Customer lastModifiedBy;
   private Integer numberOfModification = 0  ...;
```

**CustomerDTO class**

```
public class CustomerDTO {
   private Long id;
   private String name;
   private String surname;
   private String login;
   private Integer numberOfFigures;
   private Role role;}
```

**Method from Customer Controller**

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<Page<CustomerDTO>> listAll(@PageableDefault Pageable pageable) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(customerService.listAll(pageable)
            .map(customer -> modelMapper
                    .map(customer, CustomerDTO.class)), HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Customer.class)
public interface CustomerDTO {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getName();
    String getSurname();
    String getLogin();
    @Mapping("SIZE(figures)")
    Integer getNumberOfFigures();
    Role getRole();
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`CustomerDTO a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, CustomerDTO.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<CustomerDTO> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!

Comment: Can we use it if we have already implemented JPA repository for a customer?

Comment: Yeah, when you use the spring data integration you can keep the repositories as they are and just add new methods to the existing repositories.

Comment: I have created a CustomerDTOView interface that looks like the one you have presented. However, when I try to create a method in my customerRepository that extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long>, they get an error that the type "CustomerDTOView" is not compatible with "Customer". In CustomerDTOView I used @EntityView(Customer.class)

Comment: You also need to configure the integration: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/1.6/entity-view/manual/en_US/#spring-data-setup

Answer (score -1):

You could load the customers with the `figures` relationship eagerly initialized.
For this case, an entity graph would be suitable. You'd need to create a new repository method like this:

```java
@Repository
public interface CustomerRepository extends JpaRepository<Customer, Long> {

    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = "figures")
    List<Customer> findWithFiguresBy(Pageable pageable);

}
```

Then, you'd need call this repository method when searching instead of the one you are using now. With this approach, your `figures` relationship can remain lazily fetched (which is generally important as [eager fetching is a code smell](https://vladmihalcea.com/eager-fetching-is-a-code-smell/)), but whenever you need to fetch customers with the `figures` eagerly loaded, you can use this method.

If you want to lear more about entity graphs, I recommend these articles:

- [JPA Entity Graph](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-entity-graph/) by Hibernate maintainer Vlad Mihalcea
- [JPA Entity Graph](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-entity-graph) by Baeldung

Side note: if you had more than one association which needs to be loaded eagerly, you couldn't use an entity graph for that as it would [result in a MultipleBagFetchException](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/). Instead, you would load your parent entities as usual and then collect all ids into a list (say `customerIds`). Then, you'd need to load all child associations (say `figures` and `otherFigures`) by the customer id (JPQL example: `select f from Figure f where f.customer.id in :customerIds`) and place the figures in a `Map<Long, List<Figure>` (where the `Long` parameter is the customer id). Your mapper logic would then need to use the entities from the Maps for the DTOs instead  of directly from the parent entity.

Comment: No, this is the wrong solution, because using your solution(which I have already tried to implement x times), we get the WARNING mentioned in the post description. 
o.h.h.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl : HHH000104: firstResult/maxResults specified with collection fetch; applying in memory!